# A property become undefined

Tags: javascript

I im making a Clock class, and it will generate time every second.

```
class Clock {
  constructor(template) {
    this._template = template;
    this._timer = null;
  }

  render() {
    var date = new Date();

    var output = this._template
      .replace("h", date.getHours())
      .replace("m", date.getMinutes())
      .replace("s", date.getSeconds());

    console.log(output);
  }

  start() {
    this.render();
    this._timer = setInterval(this.render, 1000);
  }
}

var clock = new Clock("h:m:s");
clock.start();
```

At first, it is normal. The output same as what i expect. Then, there will be an error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. It is weird. Why my `template` property become undefined?

Comment: Where is the clock constructor invoked? sounds like `template` is originally undefined already (or likely becomes undefined before render is invoked).

Comment: @briosheje sorry, i have edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `this.render` isn't an arrow function, it will lose its `this` binding when used via `setInterval`.

Either

- make it an arrow function (`render = () => { ... }`), or
- bind it in the `setInterval` call:

  ```
      this._timer = setInterval(this.render.bind(this), 1000);
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `this.render` to the `setTimeout` function and therefore the `this` context is changed. You need to `.bind(this)` and everything will work as expected.

```js
class Clock {
  constructor(template) {
    this._template = template;
    this._time = null;
  }

  render() {
    var date = new Date();

    var output = this._template
      .replace("h", date.getHours())
      .replace("m", date.getMinutes())
      .replace("s", date.getSeconds());

    console.log(output);
  }

  start() {
    this.render();
    this._timer = setInterval(this.render.bind(this), 1000); // <-- here
  }
}

new Clock('h:m:s').start();
```

Comment: Or use arrow function :)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev yes, it's also possible ;)